# Qual atributo utilizar para deixar toda a área de um checkbox selecionável?

Tags: html

Quero fazer com que o "texto de exemplo" do código:

```html
<label for=valueexemplo>
<input type=checkbox value=valueexemplo>Texto de Exemplo
</label
```

fique com toda a área de texto selecionável, como se estivesse clicando em no próprio checkbox, porém clicando no texto.

Comment: O atributo `for` da tag `label` recebe um `id` do elemento e não um `value`, esse é o problema, correto: `<label for="valueexemplo">
<input type=checkbox id="valueexemplo">Texto de Exemplo
</label>` ... [Veja o documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O 'FOR' que você utilizou resolve o seu problema, só precisa escrever ele certinho.

A ideia é que você tenha no seu checkbox um ID a qual quando o usuário clicar no label ele aponta via o FOR, para o ID do checkbox que será chamado.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="opcao" name="check" checked>
<label for="opcao">Opção</label>
```

Veja mais aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox